# Visual leak detector (VLD) displays empty call stack

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks, visual-leak-detector

I'm using visual leak detector. It displays the call stack properly for some leaks, but I get some outputs that the call stack is empty like this:

```
---------- Block 131148 at 0x69B3AF68: 144 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0xCA7D251C, Count: 1, Total 144 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 1600):
  Data:
    B8 0A 80 01    01 00 00 00    7F 7D 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ .}......
    00 00 00 00    A4 81 1A 00    17 00 00 00    A8 AE EA 4E     ........ .......N
    40 EE 22 53    00 00 70 42    FB 19 CC BD    D4 E7 2E 00     @."S..pB ........
    CD CD CD CD    80 2D FB 6E    A0 4A B2 69    20 8D 00 54     .....-.n .J.i...T
    D8 6B 6A 54    00 CD CD CD    38 DB 81 01    40 EE 22 53     .kjT.... 8...@."S
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    B0 AF B3 69    CD CD CD CD     ........ ...i....
    60 DB 81 01    40 EE 22 53    E8 03 00 00    CD CD CD CD     `...@."S ........
    C8 AF B3 69    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ...i.... ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    00 00 00 00    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
```

I don't know how to track issues like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try to change the output format from `ascii` to `unicode` in `vld.ini`.

Your stack information must have `unicode` caracters that cannot be converted to `ascii`.

If VLD is compiled in debug, this results in assertions.

See this related topic on VLD web site:
https://vld.codeplex.com/workitem/10606

I posted an alternative to changing vld.ini in a comment (need to modify vld sources and recompile).

Answer (score 0):

Changing `ascii` to `unicode` in `vld.ini` does not work for me.

But moving my project from **directory that contains unicode chars** (such as Chinese Characters) to not-containing-unicode-chars-directory, vld does show call stack.